# Will spinning a bullet really fast without changing its linear velocity make it do more damage?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, collision, projectile, aerodynamics

The damage caused by a solid projectile can be roughly approximated with its kinetic energy, since all of that energy will be dissipated into the target on impact (in an ideal scenario, ignoring complications such as overpenetration depending on the properties of the projectile vs. the properties of the target). The general case of this makes intuitive sense. If you make a bullet go faster, or make it heavier, it will "hit harder".

However, what about the kinetic energy from the projectile rotating on its axis of flight? If you purely make a bullet spin faster, without altering its velocity in the direction in which it impacts the target, will it actually do more damage? It definitely has more kinetic energy, and the kinetic energy should also be imparted into the target on impact.

But intuitively it doesn't seem like e.g. a 5g bullet flying at 1000 m/s spinning at **1 000 000** *<s>600</s>* rpm would "hit harder" than a 5g bullet flying at 1000 m/s spinning at **350 000** *<s>300</s>* rpm.

Edit: amended example values for rpm

Comment: On which of the three possible axes of rotation is the bullet spinning?

Comment: The faster-spinning bullet _has more energy_, so it seems intuitive that it would _impart_ that energy to the target, thus _dealing more damage_.

Comment: One thing that might help with the intuition: bullets can put a hole in you, and they can also knock you back. I suspect that a bullet rotating very quickly will put a bigger hole in you, and knock you back about the same as a normal bullet would. In other words, it wouldn't hit "harder", but "wider", so to speak. (This is mostly a guess, though. I'm certainly not a ballistics expert!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you are right, for the following reason.

The spinning bullet possesses rotational kinetic energy. If the bullet is disrupted by striking a lump of meat, that kinetic energy has to go *somewhere*. At the instant that the bullet breaks up into fragments, there is no longer any force holding the rotating parts of the bullet together anymore and they want to depart with a tangential velocity- which does damage as it passes through the meat.

Note that *flywheels* used for energy storage and as lowpass filters in automobile engines must be enclosed by *scatter shields* which are designed to absorb that angular kinetic energy of an exploding flywheel, so the fragments do not kill people in the vicinity.

Comment: Even if the bullet does not break up, tumbling alone will cause more damage already. And tumble it will once it hits something. In [dumdum bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_bullet) spinning was part of the design.

Comment: Like stab and twist with a knife.

Comment: @DKNguyen, how pleasant! I'd personally prefer implosion.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Stab and twist. Repeat after me. Stab and twist. Stab and twist. Just like that.

Answer (score 13):

For comparison, the translational KE of the bullet you describe is about 2500 J while the rotational KE is about 278 J when rotating at $10^6$ rpm (assuming a 9 mm diameter and treating the bullet as a uniform cylinder), and less at lower rotation speeds. So if your numbers are realistic then the additional rotational KE is a little over 10% of the translational KE.  While this is a significantly larger fraction than I originally thought, it's still true that the KE of a bullet is largely due to its translational motion rather than its rotational motion.

As a rule, the rotational KE can be estimated by looking at the part of the object that's moving the fastest (the surface of the bullet in this case) and calculating the translational KE it *would* have if the whole object was at that speed. So to get the rotational KE of the bullet to be comparable to its translational KE, you'd have to spin it fast enough that its surface was moving at 1000 m/s or more.  Even at $10^6$ rpm, the surface of the bullet still only has a speed of about 470 m/s in its rotation.

Comment: I have amended the rotational speeds to be more realistic. It is now 1000000rpm vs 350000rpm. How much difference would the rotational KE energy make relative to the translational KE of the bullet in this case? Also, if you don't mind, could you go into detail on how the difference in rotational energy will manifest in terms of the damage the bullet does on impact?

Comment: good point.. although the 2.5uJ number seems to be surprisingly low. -NN

Comment: @nielsnielsen Yes, I got the numbers for rpm wildly wrong in the OP, they have now been amended.

Comment: @CelibateHetaerism: I've updated my answer. The rotational KE is  still less than 1% of the translational KE.

Comment: for comparison the kinetic energy of a single droplet  of ink from an inkjet printhead is 1/2x(droplet mass)x(velocity squared), mass = 20 nanograms, velocity = 10m/sec

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Are you sure your numbers are correct? From my calculations, 1 million rpm = 16666 rotations per second, which multiplied by the circumference of a bullet that is 0.009m in diameter gives the surface of the bullet moving at a speed of 471 m/s. Using your estimate formula, a 0.005kg bullet moving at 471 m/s has a kinetic energy of 554 joules which is a considerable amount of energy relative to the translational energy of the bullet.

Comment: @CelibateHetaerism:  Shoot, you're right — I forgot to convert from revolutions/second to radians/second when I calculated things.  Updated again.  (There is an extra factor of 1/2 involved in the exact calculation, which stems from the fact that not all the particles in a rotating cylinder are moving at the same speed.)

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is an effect that can (theoretically) decrease damage with increased spin rates. I heard that some bullets quickly lose spin rate and, therefore, stability when hitting a body and thus cause more damage. Increased spin rate can increase stability of the bullet within the body and thus decrease damage.

Comment: Increased spin rate = More rotational inertia, which helps rotating objects maintain the direction of the rotation axis. Seems intuitive to me that it improves penetration and thus "damage" in general.

Comment: @iBug not if it results in the bullet going all the way through the target instead of stopping inside.  Some of that damage will occur to whatever's behind the target instead.

Comment: @iBug there's the (irrelevant here I think) intermediate axis theorem though.

Comment: @iBug : Yes, more rotational inertia helps maintain the direction of the rotation axis. As a result, the bullet maintains its orientation and leaves a narrow channel after it exits the body. If the bullet changes its orientation, the channel can become much wider and the damage much more terrible.